# почему в области then переменная result имеет значение а за пределами нет и как это исправить

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
 const config = require('./config');
   const mysql = require('mysql2/promise'); 
   var result ;
   
async function main() {  
  
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(config);  
    const qantity= await connection.execute('SELECT count(1) FROM `quotes`');  
    connection.end()
    return qantity[0][0]['count(1)'];  
}   

 
main().then((res) =>{

       result = res
       console.log(res)
       //3
     
});
 console.log(result)
 //undefined 

 

 - Элемент списка
```

Comment: Потому что сначала выводится result, затем выполняется запрос к бд, затем выводится res

Comment: Обновил свой ответ. В следующий раз пожалуйста, если появились какие-то вопросы, то спрашивайте в комментарии к ответу, а не изменяйте вопрос.

Comment: это же асинхронная функция.... а console.log исполняется синхронно. на тот момент в result ещё нет ничего...запрос ещё не успел выполниться........см. ответы дубликаты...исправить - никак - делай так в then    или см.  вот этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476674/191482

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что сначала вы вызываете функцию `main`, которая выполняется асинхронно. Т.к. она асинхронная, то `javascript` идет дальше по коду и выполняет строчку `console.log(result)`, и выводит `undefined` т.к. вы переменной `result` ничего не присвоили.

И как только функция `main` закончила свою работу, вызывается стрелочная функция в `then`, в которой присваивается значение `result`, ну и выполняется строчка `console.log(result)`.

---

Увидел, обновление вопроса...

Можно в `then` после присвоения `result` вызывать функцию, которая продолжит выполнение кода. Например:

```js
main().then((res) =>{
  result = res;
  console.log(res);
  someNextFunction();
});

function someNextFunction() {
  console.log(result);
}
```

Или создать еще одну асинхронную функцию, куда поместить вызов `main` и дождаться его выполнения (`await`), после чего вызвать `console.log`. Например:

```js
async function run() {
  await main().then((res) => {
    result = res;
    console.log(res);
  });

  console.log(result);
}

run();
```